# sqldatabse not taking non english characters

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

i am trying to enter हिन्दी in my sqltable.
I made the collation as utf8_unicode_ci in the table
when i echo the variable in the php page its showing हिन्दी
but in database it gets weird values like "& #2361;& #2367;&#2344"

My code is as follows :

```
 <?php
include("connection.php");
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');

$var=$_POST['var'];
$var1=$_POST['var1'];

$query="insert into test values('$var','$var1')";


if($result=mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
echo $var;
echo $var1;

echo "success";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML entities which you get from the browser, and are shown in any browser as Unicode characters.

Even if you would read them from the database only to display them in HTML (everything could look fine), it is better not to have this kind of garbage in the database.

In the HTML form deliver the form as UTF-8 and say that the server accepts UTF-8 back:

```
<form action="... .php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

(I assume that the page already delivers in UTF-8; its Content-Type.)

The `$_POST` will hold pure Unicode characters instead of entities.

---

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

// Immediately after the connection
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    ...
    ?>

Comment: thanks i am getting the required input in database but unable to retrive and display it show ??? when i echo from php

Comment: Did you succeed finally? It seems that initially your PHP was not delivered as UTF-8 too. Or was it still the database definition?

Comment: I was successful in getting utf-8 enteries in databases. But when i retrieve it won't display it. Its showing ???? charachters.

Comment: I have added a Content-Type header which is telling the browser that the bytes are UTF-8. However the database is handled wrong as a question mark appears. Added an explicit db setting.

Answer (score 0):

Use 8-bit UCS/Unicode transformation format which works perfect for any (well most) languages

utf8_general_ci

This may help.